# error lnk2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d referenced in function in .obj file

Tags: visual-c++

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_cleanup referenced in function "int __cdecl ace_enhance_image_interp(float *,float const *,int,int,float,char const *,int)" (?ace_enhance_image_interp@@YAHPEAMPEBMHHMPEBDH@Z)

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_destroy_plan referenced in function "int __cdecl compute_omega_trans(float *,float *,int,int,char const *)" (?compute_omega_trans@@YAHPEAM0HHPEBD@Z)

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_execute referenced in function "int __cdecl compute_omega_trans(float *,float *,int,int,char const *)" (?compute_omega_trans@@YAHPEAM0HHPEBD@Z)

Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_free referenced in function "int __cdecl ace_enhance_image_interp(float *,float const *,int,int,float,char const *,int)" (?ace_enhance_image_interp@@YAHPEAMPEBMHHMPEBDH@Z)

Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_malloc referenced in function "int __cdecl ace_enhance_image_interp(float *,float const *,int,int,float,char const *,int)" (?ace_enhance_image_interp@@YAHPEAMPEBMHHMPEBDH@Z)

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fftwf_plan_r2r_2d referenced in function "int __cdecl compute_omega_trans(float *,float *,int,int,char const *)" (?compute_omega_trans@@YAHPEAM0HHPEBD@Z)

Error   7   error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals

These are the errors im getting when trying to build the code?can some one please help me..

I linked the libraries correctly..I followed this page and did all which is said here... http://liuxingguang.blogspot.in/2012/05/use-fftw-in-c.html

Comment: Give some background to your project, is it all your code, any libraries, has it ever worke...

Comment: From the minimal information you've supplied, it looks at first sight like you are linking to FFTW but have not included the relevant `.lib` in the Linker section of your project properties.

Comment: I linked the libraries in the linker section..I have added few details now for the question.